# Binding from Database to ListPicker

Tags: database, list, data-binding, windows-phone-8, listpicker

I want to populate my ListPicker with the entries that I have in a database named FriendsClass.

My XAML:

```
<toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="friendPicker" SelectionMode="Multiple" Margin="129,283,10,119" BorderBrush="#FF8DCDC1" IsEnabled="False">
    <toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
</toolkit:ListPicker>
```

My CS:

```
 SplitDataContext db = new SplitDataContext("Data Source=isostore:/S.sdf");

 List<FriendsClass> source = new List<FriendsClass>();
 var friendQuery = from friend in db.Friends select friend;

 foreach (var friend in friendQuery)
 {
     source.Add(new FriendsClass(){Name = friend.Name});
 }
 this.friendPicker.ItemsSource = source;
```

When I run my app, the ListPicker displays **"Split.ViewModels.FriendsClass"** instead of the name itself.

Here is my list of friends
[image]

But here is what appears on my ListPicker
[image]

What have I been missing? I've tried putting a ToList() function on my query but it's still the same.  When I bind my ListPicker to my Friends table in the XAML, absolutely nothing appears.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: any screenshot of emulator?

Comment: @techloverr sorry but it says i have to have more reputation points to post a picture. Instead of the friend's Name, "Split.ViewModels.FriendsClass" appears.

Comment: @ok then can you email me?

Comment: @techloverr I have uploaded screenshots for your reference. Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: can you checked the source? pls paste here

Comment: @techloverr I just checked, there is no problem with the database query, the problem is with the adding of each entry to the List

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out: I used **FullModeItemTemplate** instead of the regular **ItemTemplate** in my xaml.

```
<toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="friendPicker" SelectionMode="Multiple" Margin="129,283,10,119" BorderBrush="#FF8DCDC1" IsEnabled="False" >
    <toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>             
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
</toolkit:ListPicker>
```